# Docker registry on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, docker, docker-registry

*While running on localhost has its uses, most people want their registry to be more widely available. To do so, the Docker engine requires you to secure it using TLS, which is conceptually very similar to configuring your web server with SSL.
Get a certificate
**Assuming that you own the domain myregistrydomain.com, and that its DNS record points to the host where you are running your registry**, you first need to get a certificate from a CA.*

from the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

I want to configure this for a registry which will be running on an ec2 instance of AWS. Do I still need additional configuration for this DNS or can I just use: 
`ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` as the domain?

So as CNAME for my certificate: `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

and as tag: 
    docker tag ubuntu `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/ubuntu`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what kind of protection you want.

You can only buy a certificate from a CA for a domain that you own. You cannot buy one for ec2-xxx....amazonaws.com. So the options are

- Get a self-signed certificate (for either the ec2-xxx hostname or another domain that you own, and is mapped to that EC2 instance). This will only protect the stream of bytes and won't actually "validate" to clients that you are the server you claim to be.
- Buy a certificate from a CA for a domain that you own (e.g. www.abc.com) and is mapped to that EC2 instance. This will let clients connecting to the registry validate that your server is who is claims to be (www.abc.com).

Comment: Thanks, I'm in an test-environment so I'm using selfsigned certificates. So I want to generate my selfsigned certificate with CNAME ec2-xxx?

Comment: @Jenson You can generate a self-signed certificate for any domain name, including ec2-xxx.

Comment: Thanks, I've generated it and started my container and copied the certificate into the path. now I have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288371/docker-private-registry-using-selfsigned-certificates

Comment: @Jenson I have added a response there, it may or may not apply to your problem.